# syncfusion_flutter_PDF add photos

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How can I put a photo in this place I want in the PDF?
I want add photo this code block(contentRow1.cells[0].value = 'fotoğraflar gelecek';)

```
    Future<PdfGrid> _addContentRow_2(
    String srNo,
    PdfGrid grid,
    PdfStringFormat format,
    PdfStringFormat middleFormat,
    PdfPaddings padding) async {
  //Add a row
  final PdfGridRow contentRow1 = grid.rows.add();
  //Set height
  contentRow1.height = 150;
  //Set values and style properties
  //contentRow1.cells[0].value = srNo;
  contentRow1.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
  //Set row span
  contentRow1.cells[0].rowSpan = 1;
  contentRow1.cells[0].value = 'fotoğraflar gelecek';
  contentRow1.cells[0].columnSpan = 4;

  return grid;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that Syncfusion products, despite being present in source form in the Pub, are *not* open source. They are available under a commercial license, which may result in financial liability.

Comment: how else can i do